# UICollectionView is not updated when data is fetched

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit

Can somebody help? The function `fetchUser()` is working and I see the users being loaded, but the cells of the collection view are not appearing. It's also programmatically.

The collection view is:

```
let newCollection: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collection = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    collection.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    collection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collection.isScrollEnabled = true
    return collection
}()
```

and the collection view cells configured are:

```
extension WorkerUICollection: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return worker.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CustomeCell
        let cellUsers = worker[indexPath.item]
        cell.textLabel.text! = cellUsers.workerName
        //cell.workerLocation.text! = "2.0 km"
        cell.backgroundColor  = .white
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 3
        //cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "user")
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 150, height: 250)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3)
    }

}
```

The fetchUser() function:

```
func fetchUser() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let worker = WorkerInfo()
            worker.workerName = (dictionary["username"] as! String?)!
            //user.profileImageURL = dictionary["profileImageURL"] as! String?
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.newCollection.reloadData()
            })
        }
        print(snapshot)
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How does `fetchUser()` works? Add this method to your post.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: The frame of the `newCollection` is `0,0,0,0`, how/when do you make it "visible"? Also you have `worker.count`, so I guess you have an array `worker`, if that's so, `workers` would be a better name, but I don't know where you append that new value from FireBase (`worker.append()`)

Comment: Thanks!!!! It works now!

Comment: I forgot the  self.worker.append(worker) at the fetchUser() function

Answer (score 1):

because your self.worker.count = 0. In your `fetchUser()` function you should to update your datasource (worker) whit new one from your database. Try something like this.

```
if let array = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
   var tempWorkersArray: [WorkerInfo] = []

   for dict in array {
        let worker = WorkerInfo()
        worker.workerName = (dict["username"] as? String) ?? ""
        tempWorkersArray.append(worker)
   }
   self.worker = tempWorkersArray

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.newCollection.reloadData()
   }
}
```